# UTC time record repeating 1:00 to 1:59 am twice, 5 hours before start of Daylight saving

Tags: visual-c++, dst

UTC time record, 5 hours before start of Spring Day Light Saving, displays 1:00 to 1:59 am twice. when local time goes to 8:59 pm to 9:00 pm on 11 March '17, UTC time goes back from 1:59 am to 1:00 am and then again records time upto 1:59 am. And when local time goes to 9:59 pm to 10:00 pm same day, UTC time records 1:59 am to 3:00 am. It all happening before start of Day light saving.

Summary:
local time duration         -----------------    UTC time duration
          (11th March '17)   ---------------------    (12th March '17)
         8:00pm to 8:59 pm --------------     1:00 am to 1:59 am
         9:00pm to 9:59 pm --------------     1:00 am to 1:59 am
         10:00 pm onwards  ---------------     3:00 am onwards

```
double TimeCalculationClass :: GetUTCTime()
{
   struct tm*   starTime; 
   struct tm stmTime;
   time_t localTimestamp = (long)m_dTime;
   double dTime;
   SYSTEMTIME   sysTime, sysUTcST;
   FILETIME  locFileTime, utcFileTime;

   dTime = m_dTime;

   /* Convert to a SYSTEMTIME */
   sysTime.wSecond = (unsigned short)starTime->tm_sec;
   sysTime.wMinute = (unsigned short)starTime->tm_min;
   sysTime.wHour = (unsigned short)starTime->tm_hour;
   sysTime.wDay = (unsigned short)starTime->tm_mday;
   sysTime.wMonth = (unsigned short)(starTime->tm_mon + 1);
   sysTime.wYear = (unsigned short)(starTime->tm_year + 1900);
   sysTime.wMilliseconds = 0;

   /* convert to a local FileTime */
   SystemTimeToFileTime(&sysTime, &locFileTime);

   /* convert local filetime to a file time based on the Coordinated 
   Universal Time (UTC). */
   LocalFileTimeToFileTime(&locFileTime, &utcFileTime);

   /* convert utc filetime to utc system time */
   FileTimeToSystemTime(&utcFileTime, &sysUTcST);

   /* convert system time to struct tm */
   stmTime.tm_sec = sysUTcST.wSecond;
   stmTime.tm_min = sysUTcST.wMinute;
   stmTime.tm_hour = sysUTcST.wHour;
   stmTime.tm_mday = sysUTcST.wDay;
   stmTime.tm_mon = sysUTcST.wMonth - 1;
   stmTime.tm_year = sysUTcST.wYear - 1900;
   stmTime.tm_wday = sysUTcST.wDayOfWeek;
   stmTime.tm_yday = 0;
   stmTime.tm_isdst = 0;
   dTime = (double)mktime(&stmTime);

   //if (stTime.wMilliseconds != 0)
   dTime = dTime + ((double)sysTime.wMilliseconds / 1000);

   return dTime;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You merely discovered that local time is ambiguous.  During the hour of the DST transition in the spring the clock is set back so the same local time appears twice.  So there are two possible UTC times that could match.  You got the lowest one.  If you don't have any record of whether the local time was recorded before or after the DST transition then you just don't know which UTC timestamp is correct.  Plan for a more thorough fix, only record UTC.

Comment: my problem is the time recorded here is 4 hours(local time) before time saving starts. UTC shouldn't have deviation in any case though. Time difference of 5 hours should have maintained till 1:59 am local time.

Comment: The code you show reads an uninitialized variable `starTime`.

Comment: `SystemTimeToFileTime` expects time in UTC, not local. I suspect your sequence of calls ends up applying TZ offset twice. You may want to try `TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime` - it converts `SYSTEMTIME` holding local time to `SYSTEMTIME` holding UTC time in one hop.